# how to grab unser inputed data from one function and use in another python

Tags: python, function, variables, global

this is probably an easy answer and having to do something to do with global variables maybe? how can i get a user inputted data from one function and have it able to be called and outputted with other functions in the same program. For example:

```
hydro = False
    def main():
        medium = input("soil or hydro")

    def second():
        if medium == "hydro":
            hydro = True


main()
second()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this problem using global variables: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them). However, it's a better practice in Python to use [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), and keep functions that share variables, along with the variables they share, in a particular class.

In your code, that would look something like this:

```
class MediumHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hydro = False

    def main(self):
        self.medium = input("soil or hydro")

    def second(self):
        if self.medium == "hydro":
            self.hydro = True

handler = MediumHandler()
handler.main()
handler.second()
```

Notice the use of `self.` in each of the uses of `medium` and `hydro`. This attaches the variables to the object instead of leaving them in the global environment.

Comment: oh yes i slightly remember classes now. Its been about 3 years since my studies at The University of Kentucky.

So if i have 4 data inputs from the user, (CFL or HID ; HYDRO or SOIL ; Number of plants ; square footage.) would i then have to create 4 classes for each?

Comment: No, definitely not: you could store all of them as different variables in your class. Perhaps call it `InputHandler` or just `Input` rather than `MediumHandler`.

Comment: what is the def __init__(self): function for?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use classes then just make sure to use global variables:

```
hydro = False
medium = ''
def main():
    global medium
    medium = raw_input("soil or hydro: ")


def second():
    global medium
    global hydro
    if medium == "hydro":
        hydro = True

main()
print medium
second()
print hydro
```

Also note that I used `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input` wouldn't work for your case because you want the string to remain a string.

Comment: My bad. I use python 2.7. In python 3 raw_input() was renamed to input()